# How to get a math textbook that's out of publication?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

I recently decided I wanted to learn more about the Dehn invariant, so I did what I always do and went on MSE and MO to get recommendations.  I found [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258643/intuition-behind-the-dehn-invariant), which suggested a book called "Theory of convex bodies" by Bonnesen and Fenchel ([ISBN 9780914351023](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780914351023)).  Unfortunately, the book seems to be out of publication, and I can't find any used copies or electronic versions.  Moreover, my local university library doesn't have it in the catalog.

> Is there any way for me to see this book?  What are strategies for finding old textbooks like this?

*PS: Moderators, please make this question community wiki, and/or migrate it to MO if it would be more appropriate there.*

Comment: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=%22Theory+of+convex+bodies%22+bonnesen&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def

Comment: Have you spoken to one of the reference librarians at your university? They can almost surely find it through an inter-library loan.

Comment: Used editions of the original German edition (Theorie der konvexen Körper) are available through www.vialibri.net, if that is an option.